# Striped repeating background flickers on scroll in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, background-image

Try scrolling this page up and down and watch the image below. You may notice that the image flickers. (Don't use a scroll wheel as this will likely scroll by large discrete amounts and you won't see the effect.)

[image: stripes]

To avoid this effect when using striped backgrounds, you can add the following to your CSS:

`background-attachment: fixed;`

This causes the background to remain fixed, so it will not appear to flicker when the user scrolls the page. This works fine in Chrome and Firefox ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AuGcs/)), **but not in IE.** The background-attachment feature is supposed to be supported in IE8 and above, so why isn't this working? More importantly, how can I eliminate the flicker in IE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could feed this to just IE9 (in IE8 it seems to not work on the pseudo-element, so for IE7-8 support, make it the elmeent itself) or use it for all the browsers, but actually putting it into a `fixed` element (or in this case, a pseudo-element) resolved the flicker for me ([**see fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/AuGcs/8/)):

```
.background:after {  
    content: '';
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-image: url(http://www.commentnation.com/hotlinks/diagonal_pin_stripes_background_gray_on_white.gif);
    background-attachment: fixed;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

**For IE7-8** ([**see fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/AuGcs/10/)):

```
.background {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-image: url(http://www.commentnation.com/hotlinks/diagonal_pin_stripes_background_gray_on_white.gif);
    background-attachment: fixed;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: Yep, I think using an actual fixed element is the best cross-browser solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to add

```
<script>
if(navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident\/7\./)) {
  document.body.addEventListener("mousewheel", function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    var wd = event.wheelDelta;
    var csp = window.pageYOffset;
    window.scrollTo(0, csp - wd);
  });
}
</script>
```

Comment: Please explain also further why OP needs to add your suggested script.

Answer (score -3):

I suggest you add

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

to the css if you haven't already and adjust the background-position. This may help with the flicker.  Also make sure you are using the correct DOCTYPE to support background-attachment.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but the question is regarding a repeated background, so adding `no-repeat` is not an option.